# Create folder with powershell in sharepoint (webservices)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to create a folder in sharepoint if it does not already exist. My powershell script is not running on the sharepoint server so I think I have to use the sharepoint web services? I am currently uploading files to sharepoint with powershell using webclient as below - but I need to create the folder for the file first... if it does not already exist;

```
# Upload the file
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = $credentials
$webclient.UploadFile($destination + "/" + $File.Name, "PUT", $File.FullName)
```

Is this possible to do with webclient? If not, how can this be done using the sharepoint web services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned SharePoint Web Services, [Lists.UpdateListItems Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) could be utilized for that purpose, for example:

```
Function Create-Folder([string]$WebUrl,[string]$ListUrl,[string]$ListName,[string]$FolderName)
{
     $url = $WebUrl +  "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?WSDL" 
     $listsProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $url  -UseDefaultCredential

     $batch = [xml]"<Batch OnError='Continue' RootFolder='$WebUrl/$ListUrl'><Method ID='1' Cmd='New'><Field Name='ID'>New</Field><Field Name='FSObjType'>1</Field><Field Name='BaseName'>$FolderName</Field></Method></Batch>"
     $result = $listsProxy.UpdateListItems($ListName, $batch) 
}
```

**Usages**

Create `Orders` folder under `Documents` library:

```
Create-Folder -WebUrl "http://contoso.intranet.com" -ListUrl "Documents" -ListName "Documents" -FolderName "Orders"
```

Create `2014` folder in `Requests` list:

```
Create-Folder -WebUrl "http://contoso.intranet.com" -ListUrl "Lists/Requests" -ListName "Requests" -FolderName "2014"
```

**Update**

If folder already exists then SOAP service will throw the error:

> The operation failed because an unexpected error occurred. (Result
>   Code: 0x8107090d)

but since `OnError` attribute is set to `Continue` for [Batch Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms437562%28v=office.15%29.aspx), PowerShell will continue the execution.

Comment: Thanks - really helpful! will this error (and thus continue) if the folder already exists?